# WPF Textbox Trigger IsMouseOver

Tags: wpf

It's so difficult now with styles in wpf. Why Triggers does not work???

```
<TextBox x:Name="txbUsername" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                 Width="350" Height="20" Margin="5 0 0 0" BorderThickness="0 0 0 1" Background="#eff0f1">
            <TextBox.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif"></Setter>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0 0 0 1"></Setter>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#a70711"></Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBox.Style>
        </TextBox>
```

Comment: Works for me. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: When I click on textbox than bottom border must be red

Comment: Click is not the same as mouse over. However, your Style works.

Comment: IsFocused it doesn't work too

Comment: Emma, please note that "it does not work" is not a sufficient problem description. You should tell us exactly what you are trying to achieve (since we can't read your mind), what you've tried and what unexpected or erroneous behaviour you're observing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a custom `ControlTemplate`:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txbUsername" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
         Width="350" Height="20" Margin="5 0 0 0" BorderThickness="0 0 0 1" Background="#eff0f1">
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                        <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="false" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="border" Value="0.56"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0 0 0 1"></Setter>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#a70711"></Setter>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

The reason for this is that there are some triggers defined in the default `ControlTemplate` that cannot be override by simply defining some custom `Style` triggers.